# Negative coordinates for WGS84 system are invisible - ArcGIS 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, csv, import, wgs84

I have a csv file with point coordinates in GCS_WGS_1984 geographic system. I've imported it to ArcMap as a XY file however negative values for West hemisphere are not visible (but ALL records are in Table of Contents - even negative).

I've tried to save data in other formats, I've changed XY columns to Float type - nothing helps...

I want to generate a raster based on the coordinates - unfortunately, the raster doesn't cover area with negative coordinates...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known issue that pops up now and again with adding XY data that's been ongoing for years ([see this ArcGIS Knowledge Base article](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/39972)):

From section #3:

> There is a missing negative from the X field values when the values
>   are decimal degrees (geographic coordinates).
>
> SOLUTION: Use the field calculator to add a negative to the X field's
>   values.
>
> REASON: For data in the US, most of the decimal degree values will be
>   negative X and positive Y. This is because of how decimal degrees are
>   displayed eastward and westward of the prime meridian. The breakdowns
>   of values for each hemisphere are below:
>
> • Northern: +Y
>   • Southern: -Y
>   • Western: -X
>   • Eastern: +X